# Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0' in debian

Tags: php, linux

hi am using a Kali linux Rolling 2020.4 last update and every thing is okay from 2 years until now after i add the PPA of php and update every thing for last update
when i run

```
sudo apt install php8.0
```

i get error

```
E: Unable to locate package php8.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0'
```

but i dont know what's the problem
here's the ppa and have php8

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/
```

and here too

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/
```

the following command is was i used

```
sysadmin@debian-10:~$ sudo apt install -y lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget
sysadmin@debian-10:~$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sysadmin@debian-10:~$ echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to Install PHP8.0 and php8.0-pgsql on Ubuntu 21.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480406/unable-to-install-php8-0-and-php8-0-pgsql-on-ubuntu-21-04)

Answer (score 27):

### Install PHP 8 on Debian

For Debian Buster (10) and Debian Bullseye (11)

With root access:

```bash
apt update && apt install -y wget gnupg2 lsb-release
wget https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg && apt-key add apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt update && apt install -y php8.1
php -v # Outputs "PHP 8.1.3 ..."
```

*This doesn't works for:*

- Since June 2022, Debian Stretch (9) ([info](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/))
- Since June 2020, Debian Jessie (8) ([info](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/))
- see [available distributions](https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/)

### Install PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu

Until 21.04 [as described in @NicoHaase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71480798/9193372)

```bash
sudo apt update && apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y php8.1
php -v # Outputs "PHP 8.1.3 ..."
```