# Unable to Install PHP8.0 and php8.0-pgsql on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to install php8.0-pgsql on my local system, but failed to install as version is not available on ubuntu release hairsuite. So for this I have remove my PHP version from my local system and try to re-install the PHP8.0 on my local system but failed to install as I have implemented different solutions like PPA and certificates but no success. Now when run following commands to install PHP8.0 to system facing following error

installation commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php8.0
sudo apt install php8.0-common php8.0-cli
```

Error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0'
```

I don't know what is root cause of this issue as I have spent a lot of time in searching the errors but failed. Anyone suggest helpfull solution that how I can install php on my system with PHP8.0-pgsql too.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 21.04 has reached its end of life in January 2022, and `ondrej/php` does not support any EOL version. You need to upgrade your Ubuntu version first to be able to use this repository again

Comment: "Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided." from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php